# Receiving an ActiveRecord::Relation object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a method that is used to sort columns of a table. Jenkin fail on a Rspec which its method implemented this way:

```
def exec
    my_requests = MyRequest.joins(user: :roles)
    return my_requests.group(:id,'users.first_name','users.last_name','roles.title').order(order_binds) unless search_query.any?
    my_requests.where(sanitized_sql).group(:id,'users.first_name','users.last_name','roles.title').order(order_binds)
end
```

Before I add **'roles.title'** I was getting a passing build and tested sorting functionality successfully, but not sure what is the issue when I add roles.title. It output the below error. Looks like it returns an #<ActiveRecord::Relation [actual result] > instead of the [actual result]:

```
 expected: [#<MyRequest id: 27, requestor_id: 93, sample_name: nil, item_numbers: ["SID123123XYZ"], written_at_begin...at: "2022-02-25 04:41:12", updated_at: "2022-02-25 04:41:12", PMI_numbers: [], request_status: nil>]
20:43:48              

got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<MyRequest id: 27, requestor_id: 93, sample_name: nil, item_numbers: ["SID123123XYZ"], written_at_begin...at: "2022-02-25 04:41:12", updated_at: "2022-02-25 04:41:12", PMI_numbers: [], request_status: nil>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `to_ary` (alias `to_a`) method on the relation to convert it to an array. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_ary